# How to get datacontext at window unloaded event at code behind

Tags: wpf

When I try  to get datacontext at code behind on window unloaded event on usercontrol.xaml.cs file then it gives datacontext to null. Currently I am using
**ViewModel objViewModel=(ViewModel)this.datacontext**
on window unloaded event.So is there is another way to get datacontext on window  unloaded event on code behind file?

Comment: Unload is unloaded.  You might try close or closing.

Comment: When was the `DataContext` set?  Assuming it *was* set, some other code may be clearing it.  Do you create the window and set the `DataContext` yourself, or is there a framework doing that for you?

Comment: @Blam It's a usercontrol not window page.So there is no close or closing event

Comment: I would suggest you that as you are not able to close your usercontrol  you can set visiblity and on the basis of visiblity change use VisibilityChanged Event of usercontrol and do your require option and you wont get datacontext null as well

Comment: Then why is the question at window unloaded event?

Comment: @Blam sorry by mistake it type.It's a usercontrol.Can u provide me solution for that

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to [datacontextchanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontextchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event and handle this as the unload for your view model.